# How To Serve Files With HttpServer In Dart

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have the following standard structure for my Dart app:

```
/
  pubspec.yaml
  web/
    main.css
    main.dart
    main.html
  build.dart
  server.dart
```

When I receive GET requests on the server, I want the server to use the `web` directory as root and serve the content of the files to clients.

How can I do this?

This is how far I've gotten so far:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 80).then((HttpServer server) {
      server.listen((request) { 
        print("got request");

        switch (request.method) {
          case 'GET':
            // Do I need to send the file here? ... 
            // if not fount then send HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
            break;

          default:

        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Also have a look at the great collection of shelf_xxx packages https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=shelf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dart website contains a small sample on [Writing web servers](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/io/#writing-web-servers) which shows how to serve pages. in your case because your `server.dart` file is in the root directory (for future reference, it's generally recommended that CLI scripts designed to be run be held in a `bin` directory per the [Package Layout Conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html#command-line-apps)), you will need to append 'web/' to the arguments passed to the script.

Additionally, note that the 'Options' class used in the sample has been deprecated and you should use the [dart:io Platform.script](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_io/Platform.html#script) property instead.

That said, I highly suggest you look at using the [route package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route) to handle server requests as it easily allows for assigning various callbacks depending on a matching pattern (including request methods).

Comment: Took a simplified approach for now.  Btw, Path class in the linked sample has been killed - had to use something else.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the latest version of my code after [Matt B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479964/matt-b)'s answer:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

String _basePath;

_sendNotFound(HttpResponse response) {
  response.write('Not found');
  response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  response.close();
}


_handleGet(HttpRequest request) {
  // PENDING: Do more security checks here?
  final String stringPath = request.uri.path == '/' ? '/main.html' : request.uri.path;
  final File file = new File(path.join(_basePath, stringPath));
  file.exists().then((bool found) {
    if (found) {
      file.openRead().pipe(request.response).catchError((e) { });
    } else {
      _sendNotFound(request.response);
    }
  });
}


_handlePost(HttpRequest request) {

}


void main() {
  _basePath = Platform.environment['HOME'];

  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 80).then((HttpServer server) {
    server.listen((request) { 
      switch (request.method) {
        case 'GET':
          _handleGet(request);
          break;

        case 'POST':
          _handlePost(request);
          break;

        default:
          request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
          request.response.close();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is already included in pub.

```
$ pub serve --help

Run a local web development server.

By default, this serves "web/" and "test/", but an explicit list of 
directories to serve can be provided as well.

Usage: pub serve [directories...]
-h, --help               Print this usage information.
    --mode               Mode to run transformers in.
                         (defaults to "debug")

    --all                Use all default source directories.
-D, --define             Defines an environment constant for dart2js.
    --hostname           The hostname to listen on.
                         (defaults to "localhost")

    --port               The base port to listen on.
                         (defaults to "8080")

    --[no-]dart2js       Compile Dart to JavaScript.
                         (defaults to on)

    --[no-]force-poll    Force the use of a polling filesystem watcher.

Run "pub help" to see global options.
```

See http://dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-serve.html for detailed documentation.